# Ubuntu 16.04 & Kodi 18.1 sound question

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi, kodi

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. I have the following setup, Ubuntu 16.04 and Kodi 18.1, I've setup the Kodi on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04, Kodi worked fine from the laptop, but if I connect it to a TV through HDMI, I can see the image, but no sound, I've changed the monitor in Kodi to HDMI, it has no effect (the sound still plays on laptop), my questions:
1) how to turn on sound on my TV?
2) I can turn off the image on my laptop so it'll display only on TV, but how do I turn off the sound on laptop, right now it's playing on both laptop and TV (only image), and sound only on laptop.
ps: I also noticed this weird behavior, after I changed the monitor to HDMI and I stopped the movie, Kodi's screen has only image, no text.

Comment: In your audio / mixer settings for Ubuntu change the output port to HDMI or something similar.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer below showing the steps you took to set that so the audio works.  I will give you a +1 for that.  =)

Answer (score 1):

In your sound settings, you need to turn on your TV (or any other device connected to HDMI) with HDMI cable plugged in and TV turned on (if you don't do this, you won't see the HDMI output option), then select the HDMI output option (previously your headphone/speaker should be selected), then your sound output will be through HDMI.